# while migrating Angular application from 8 to 9

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular-cli, node-modules

while migrating the Angular application from 8 to 9 I am facing this issue.

"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'

It shows in the node modules so I am not able to do anything. I just re-installed angular/core. But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer

Find all import renderer in your code and replace with render2. Something like:
<s>import { Renderer } from '@angular/core'</s> => import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';